# ODBC Escape Syntax SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, odbc

We have an application that generates the following code and errors when running in SQL 2016. When i take it out of the application log and try doing a manual insert into SQL server 2016 it errors. I have tried changing it from "datetime2(7)" to "datetime" however I have had no luck. What i found is that its the "{ts }" causing the issue. IF i get rid of it I can insert fine. Also if i get rid of the last 3 characters on the milliseconds (209) I can insert with the "{ts }" around the SQL.

Any of you able to help get around this in SQL(some plugin i need to install?) or will this need to be changed at the application level to get rid of the {ts }?
I am also using ODBC driver 13 for SQL.

```
INSERT INTO loginlog ( loginid, id, lastlogin, ll_from ) 
VALUES ( 86708, 1, {ts '2019-11-18 13:32:22.309209'}, '1.1.1.1' )
```

Thank you

Comment: `FROM` is a [Reserved Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15); you shouldn't use it as an object's name, and if you *have* you **must** [delimit identify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15#classes-of-identifiers) it. I would recommend changing your column's name.

Comment: Hi sorry i changed the field names for this post. "from" isnt the issue but thank you.

Comment: So what is the error you get? We can only base answers on what you've given us, and you've only told us "it doesn't work". That doesn't, however, tell us much at all.

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. But once i get rid of the ts or delete the last 3 characters in miliseconds I am able to do the insert manually in sql server 2016

Comment: can you post your complete code? is your query generated by code or only the lastlogin literal? if it is a varchar maybe you can change it before the insert

Answer (score 1):

ODBC `DATETIME` is mapped on SQL Server `DATETIME` (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#converting-string-literals-to-datetime2)).

> Any assignment operation from ODBC DATETIME literals into datetime2
>   types will cause an implicit conversion between datetime

So you can't use `ODBC` to keep all that fractional part, you must use `ISO 8601` instead.

```
declare @loginlog table ( loginid int, id int, lastlogin datetime2(7), ll_from varchar(15)) 

INSERT INTO @loginlog ( loginid, id, lastlogin, ll_from ) 
VALUES ( 86708, 1, '2019-11-18T13:32:22.309209', '1.1.1.1' )

select * from @loginlog
```

Comment: Thank you, good to know. I do have the datatype set to "datetime" and i get the same result? Sorry im a bit confused on this one

Comment: `DATETIME` can handle only 0..999 in fractional part, if you want to keep 6 decimals you must use `DATETIME2`

Comment: Yes i have tried it both, My issue is with ODBC ts getting generated from the code.